# Implement DocuSign in Ionic 3 Application

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am looking to incorporate the features of DocuSign in Ionic 3 Application where I need to get PDF files signed which are confidential files.

In the [SDK & Tools](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/sdk-tools) document provided by DocuSign, I didn't see any client side implementation. How the DocuSign signing feature can be incorporated in a Hybrid Mobile Application.

Or is it possible to get a signature link by incorporating the API implementations in server side. If signature link got generated rather than email, the link can be passed to client Application and signature can be obtained with the layer.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the best approach is to make the API calls from the server. And yes, it's possible to generate the link and use what we call "embedded signing" which means that instead of an email sent to the recipient, the recipient is using your app to sign directly.
Here is a link to code examples of how to generate and envelope and use embedded signing:
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-embedded-signing (in 7 different languages, not sure which one you may want, so I didn't include code in this answer)